# Directive inner content with isolated and non-isolated scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I found quite a strange behaviour of **scope:true** type for inner content of a directive:

```
<body ng-init="x=10">
    <mydir>
       {{x}}
    </mydir> 
</body>
```

so {{x}} is inner content, and directive definition is:

```
.directive('mydir', function() {
   return {
       scope: {},
       link: function(scope){
           scope.x = 5;
       }
   };
});
```

When we define scope as isolated (**scope:{}**), it outputs {{x}} as 10, so uses outer scope. But when we create new scope for the directive(**scope:true**), it will use it for inner content and output 5. So it uses different scopes for inner content for 2 cases. Could somebody give me a hint/link to souce code/manual for the explanation for this inconsistency?

Here is [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CihQ6h35ogTzxMcKlLpz?p=preview) to play with the code.

**UPD**: I understand what is JavaScript prototype inheritance. I know the difference between directive scope types. And my aim is not to display 5 instead of 10. The question is about inner template that in both cases should be interpolated with parent scope, which does not have access to properties of child/isolated one.

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13845#issuecomment-174953398.

Comment: yes, thank you. it was created by me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A got the answer from angular issues:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13845#issuecomment-174953398

And here is source code answer:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/eae0a1121ffcc636d760463105dcdc548ea47390/src/ng/compile.js#L2538-L2545

```
var scopeToChild = scope;
if (newIsolateScopeDirective && (newIsolateScopeDirective.template || newIsolateScopeDirective.templateUrl === null)) {
      scopeToChild = isolateScope;
}
childLinkFn && childLinkFn(scopeToChild, linkNode.childNodes, undefined, boundTranscludeFn);
```

**resume:** 
In case of isolated scope type, **scope is provided ONLY for directive template**, but not for inner content.

Answer (score 5):

In your original code snippet, the `{{x}}` does not belong to `<mydir>`. You should define a template to the directive.

```
// js
.directive('mydir', function() {
   return {
       template: '{{x}}',
       scope: {},
       link: function(scope){
           scope.x = 5;
       }
   };
});

// html
<body ng-init="x=10">
    <mydir></mydir> 
</body>
```

Here is [the preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/4TuZfIHxeXRFuo795oq3?p=preview)

Comment: if it does not belong to the directive, why it outputs 5, when scope:true

Comment: It is conditional. When it is isolated scope, the inner html does not belong to the directive. You can put `{{$id}}` inside and outside of your directive to check scope id. In other words, if you set `ng-init="x1=10"`. The `{{x}}` inside your directive will not show 5 but empty string. Yeah. this is an interesting case. But usually we create a directive with template. If you embed code into directive, better consider `transclude`.

Answer (score 2):

Something not right is going on.  If you run your code in Chrome with Batarang turned on, you can see when **scope : {}** that it is indeed creating a new scope separate from the first, completely disconnected, and setting the variable to 5.  But your interpolated string is binding to outer scope.  If you set **scope : true** it is also create a new scope inherited from the outer, and the {{x}} interpolation is binding correctly.  I don't think it is scope parameter on the directive that is not working, something with binding is not working.

Comment: This is probably why btw that they say dont bind to primitives directly off scope, or if you dont have a period in your binding you are doing it wrong :-)