# AngularJS What is the benefit of binding click in angular directive over ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have seen some people binding click in there directive's link function over than ng-click.

I have researched for a long time and haven't found the answer. Can anyone give me a reason?

I have been using ng-click because it is much easier than creating a new directive,and I can get an overview in a glance.

## Example

### How I write a directive

**HTML**

```
<some-directive>
  <button ng-click="someFunction()">Lorem Ipsum</button>
</some-directive>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('myapp',[])
.directive('someDirective',function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{},
    link: function (scope,element,attrs) {

      //Code goes here

      scope.someFunction = function() {
        //callback
      }

      //More code goes here

    }
  }
})
```

### How most people write a directive

**html**

```
<some-directive>
  <button click-trigger>Lorem Ipsum</button>
</some-directive>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('myapp',[])
.directive('someDirective',function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{},
    link: function (scope,element,attrs) {

      //Code goes here

    }
  }
})
.directive('click-trigger',function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs) {

      element.bind('click',callBackFunction);

      function callBackFunction () {
        //callback
      }

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: IMO it depends. For example, if the functionality I want in my element is unique to say one page, then there is no reason for me to even use a directive (take it with a grain of salt). Think DRY - If you will use the same functionality accross your project(s), then binding to your directive will be more scalable. That's just one of the reasons I would bind to a directive vs. ng-click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More angular way in my view is to include the nested elements in a template.

```
.directive('foo', function(){
                return {                 
                 template:'<button ng-click="clickMe()">Click Me</button>'               
                }                
            })
```

The problem of your approach is that the nested DOM elements belong to the scope of the directive - not to the scope of the controller. You can very easily run in to confusion if you are trying to create isolated scopes.

Please note that angular behaves in odd ways when it comes to isolated scopes. This is unnecessarily complicated in my view.

Please study [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917448/directive-inner-content-with-isolated-and-non-isolated-scopes/34918455#34918455) question.

Comment: No Offense,but I am asking for the **benefit** of binding click over ng-click.

Comment: Thanks. The first paragraph is actually in favor of binding click.

Comment: Can you show me an example how someone has implemented a directive in the way you claimed them to have.

Comment: here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2958-managing-a-shared-global-ui-component-in-angularjs.htm. With his popupListTrigger directive

Comment: Also may I ask you how you manage a click event inside a directive?

Comment: If I need this setup I would include nested elements as a template. Then I would use ng-click to access the scope.

Answer (score 1):

It's cleaner this way. Everything is separated, you don't mix javascript with HTML. This tendency is also perceivable in vanilla JS, where you don't set `onclick` attributes on elements, yet you `addEventListener` upon loading (or anywhere in the JS code).

Comment: I generally agree with the concept of unobtrusive JavaScript. However, sometimes I ask myself the question (in this more specific case of using a directive vs ng-click): is it worth the effort? Say for example, I want to simply call a function that is part of my controller. It would be trivial to simply do `ng-click="vm.doSomething()"` directly from my button, than writing a directive, and then passing `doSomething` to it. Or maybe I am just lazy :)

Comment: I agree, I'm also lazy and with most click events I do inline :D

Comment: But I thought it is actually helpful to put ng-click in the html. So you don't need to see the script to get overview. And easier.

Comment: @LukasChen Unobtrusive JavaScript take the "cleaning" up to the next level, by removing virtually all JavaScript from the HTML and as Voreny mentioned, just binding all of the events to listeners (in a separate script file?) when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using `click` event in `directive` makes a code loosely coupled with that of the controller being invoked. If there are multiple controllers associated and the same `directive(s)` getting used, then the code becomes redundant. So a smarter way is to define the `click event` in the AngularJS custom directives itself. Moreover, when interaction with DOM of AngularJS is concerned, which is not easy, so by this way, it paves the way for the same.

Comment: "Using click event in directive makes a code loosely coupled with that of the controller being invoked."Do you mean ng-click event?

Comment: With `ng-click`, the DOM is tightly coupled with that of the controller. But with the `custom directives`, the events are loosely coupled.